# How to determine for the image room

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The linear transformation [image] is defined by [image],
where A is the matrix

[image]

And i got this question below:

Determine a base B for the image space Im(L) to L.
Explain why B is a base for
Im(L).

Should i use Gaussian to determine the Base or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images of the three standard basis vectors form a generating set for the image space, but they might be linearly dependent. What you need to do is solve a linear homogeneous system that finds any linear dependencies between those images; then any non-trivial dependency tells you that one of those image vectors can (and should) be removed, so as to obtain an independent generating set, i.e., a basis of the image space.

Comment: Thanks i will accept this answer after 10 min until then i can't